# Enviar una variable al controlador desde AJAX en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente problema, en una vista obtengo los datos de un usuario a través de un `foreach` y uno de ellos es el código, el cual mediante un enlace, ejecuto una función que le paso como parámetro el mismo código:

```php
<a  href="" onclick="cargarID(<?=$fila->Id_usuario?>)"><?=$fila->Id_usuario?></a></td>
```

La función envía el `id` a un método de mi controlador:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cargarID(id= null){
      if(id) {
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/getID/"+id,
      type:"POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(respuesta){
         window.location.href = "http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/index";
       }
     });
    }
   }
 </script>
```

Éste es mi controlador, hago esto porque necesito enviarle un parámetro a una consulta que tengo en el modelo.

```php
function index()
{
  $this->load->view('guest/section');
  $datos['arrPerfil'] = $this->model_usuario->consulta();
  $this->load->view('user/usuario_view', $datos);
}
public function getID($id) 
{
  if($id) {
    $data = $this->model_usuario->consulta($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Y cual es problema que tienes, que parte del codigo no te funciona?, en todo ese codigo existen algunos errores.

Comment: no entiendo. podrías explicar el problema??

Comment: no me llega el id al controlador, es la forma correcta de obtenerlo en mi funcion ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que la siguiente linea funciona:

```
<a  href="" onclick="cargarID(<?=$fila->Id_usuario?>)"><?=$fila->Id_usuario?></a>
```

Y esta llegando correctamente el Id_usuario.

Tu función

```
function cargarID(id= null){
      if(id) {
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/getID/"+id,
      type:"POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(respuesta){
         window.location.href = "http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/index";
       }
     });
    }
   }
```

Está mal en la parte de la llamada ajax especificamente en:

```
type:"POST",
```

Esta enviando una peticion post y en tu controlador en codeigniter lo que esperas es una peticion get

```
public function getID($id) 
{
  if($id) {
    $data = $this->model_usuario->consulta($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

No se que devuelve tu consulta en `model_usario` pero ahi deberias devolver un arreglo que después puedas recorrer con jquery o javascript.

Lo que podrías hacer es cambiar el tipo de petición en la llamada ajax de POST a GET, o mejor te recomendaría que lo hagas mediante POST y tambien cambies tu controlador en codeigniter, para que tengas mayor control de los datos que envias.

Por ejemplo tu llamada ajax quedaria:

```
function cargarID(id){
   if(id != null) {
         $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/getID",
            type:"POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'id_persona': id},
            success:function(respuesta){
             window.location.href = "http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/index";
           }
         });
   }
}
```

Y tu funcion getID en el controlador quedaría:

```
public function getID() 
{
  $id = $this->input->post("id_persona");
  if($id != null) {
    $data = $this->model_usuario->consulta($id);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `async:false`, y saca el `success` fuera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cargarID(id= null){
    if(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/getID/"+id,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).success(function(response){
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/index";
        });
    }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: quizás quieras leer el comentario que el autor publicó como respuesta.